# Make the array full before releasing data

Tags: c++, qt, bluetooth, buffer

I'm implementing a function which receives data via bluetooth and returns it in an array `unsigned char buf[10]`. This is my function, which is called every x milliseconds via a `QTimer`:

```cpp
void gui::listen_device()
{
    unsigned char crcval;

    int count = 0;

    fd_set readmask;
    struct timeval tv;

    int v = 0, v1 = 0, v2 = 0;

    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = 100000;

    int i;
    memset (buf, 0, 10);
    FD_ZERO (&readmask);
    FD_SET (sock, &readmask);
    if (select (255, &readmask, NULL, NULL, &tv) > 0)
    {
        if (FD_ISSET (sock, &readmask))
        {
            numb = read (sock, buf, 10);

                // print of counter
                printf ("%d ->", buf[0]);
                fprintf (data, "%d,", buf[0]);
                for (i = begin; i < numb-1; i++)
                {
                    v = buf[i];
                    printf ("%d,", v);
                    fprintf (data, "%d,", v);
                }

                //---------------//
                crcval = BP_CRC8(buf,9);
                printf(" crcf=%x crcc=%x", buf[9], crcval);
                if (crcval == buf[9])
                {
                    printf("crc ok\n");
                    begin = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("crc fail\n");
                    begin = numb -1;
                }
                //---------------//

                printf ("\n");
                fprintf (data, "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

I want the function to return `buf` only if it is full. So I created a global variable `begin` if the `buf` wasn't full the last time the timer came.

This is the output in the `.txt` file.

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
4,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,
5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
9,0,0,
0,0,0,
10,0,0,0,0,
11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
13,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
14,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
```

from time to time it returns me an incomplete `buf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, you must **change architecture of your program**. There are lots of holes here.

- You call some function every x milliseconds and where is guarantee, that it will be done when next x milliseconds happens.
- You run your listening from gui -- so, your gui is waiting and not repainting here. Do it in background.
- If you say, that function return something -- where is your `return`? Rewrite your code.

Hope, this advices will be helpful for you! Good luck!